# dual monitor issue - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Using an NVIDIA Geforce 960 with a dual Monitor setup which simply clones the desktop to both montiors on Windows 7

1. Monitor 1--> Insignia TV 50 inch connected via HDMI
2. Monitor 2--> Insignia TV 55 inch connected via HDMI via Sony Amp

Having an issue where the primary monitor is disabled when I turn off the secondary monitor. I have tried all combinations of **Win P** to fix the issue, but no matter what setup I have, either in Windows or in the Nvidia drivers setup the problem persists. It should be noted that turning off the primary monitor does not disable the secondary, so the problem is only unidirectional.

The setup I have is simply a cloned version of the original desktop appearing on the secondary monitor. I would like it so that if I wish to turn either of the monitors off, that the other will stay connected.

Below is an image of the multiple display setup in the NVIDIA control panel. The **Monitor 1--> Insignia TV 50 inch** is set to be the primary monitor. As you can see there seems to be the secondary monitor listed first though (I am not sure if this has any effect on this issue).

[image]

Comment: Do they share the same resolution?

Comment: @Pancakedinner  - Yes although the secondary monitor struggles to turn on in the correct resolution… It always fires up in 720, and then staggers for a bit until it goes to 1080 P like the other monitor

Answer (score 0):

he issue was with the HMDI receiver amp somehow (although I never had this issue with my previous secondary TV monitor). If I bypass the HDMI amp by sending the HDMI directly to the secondary TV monitor then Windows does not disable the primary monitor when the secondary monitor was turned off.

This does present a new problem of not having sound pumped to the amp, however I was able to send the signal from the TV back to the AMP via Optical cable.